# Wordpress JSON api fetch selected items

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

How can I fetch only post title, excerpt of all the posts of my WordPress blog using JSON api.

Currently, I am using https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts, which returns a lot of data that slows down the whole process. Is there any url where I can fetch only selected fields?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered writing your own API endpoints? https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Something like this would probably work for you where your endpoint becomes http://example.com/wp-json/myplugin/v1/post-titles:

```
   function my_awesome_func( $data ) {
     $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'post',
     );
     $query = new WP_Query( $args );

     $arr = array();
     while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
      $query->the_post();
      $titles = get_the_title();
      array_push($arr, $titles);
     }
     return $arr;
   }

   add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
     register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/post-titles', array(
       'methods' => 'GET',
       'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
     ) );
   } );
```

Comment: Can I use this in our own plugin? What will be exact url for accessing this?